# How to implement a retry in Flutter using CachedNetworkImage?

Tags: flutter

I am using CachedNetworkImage in Flutter, and I am wonder how I would implement a mechanism to retry if the image download fails?  In my example, down in the errorWidget > GestureDetector > onTap section.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final imgKey = Key(imgUrl);

    return CachedNetworkImage(
      key: imgKey,
      imageUrl: imgUrl,
      ...
      errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Center(
        child: GestureDetector(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              const Icon(
                Icons.refresh,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
              const Text('Error downloading image.'),
              const Text('Tap to retry.'),
            ],
          ),
          onTap: () { // Implement image reload here
            setState(() {
              // manager
              //     .removeFile(url)
              //     .then((value) => manager.getSingleFile(url));
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
      cacheManager: manager,
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_image instead of CachedNetworkImage;

use it like this :

```
new Image(
    image: new NetworkImageWithRetry(imageUrl),
),
```

it is saying this about caching :
https://github.com/flutter/flutter_image/blob/master/lib/network.dart#L26

Comment: This only uses in-memory caching not caching to disk like CachedNetworkImage.

Comment: doesn't even support web

Comment: @Maxgmer neither does CachedNetworkImage.